# SQL Profiler tutorials for newbie

Tags: sql-server-2008, learning, profiler

The MSDN documentation tough to understand.

Are there any online tutorials available to learn SQL Profiler? If possible, videos or simple blog posts would be preferred.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this free book from redgate:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/aloha_dba/archive/2009/01/21/mastering-sql-server-profiler-e-book-available-for-free.aspx

Brad McGee also has some videos on his website:
http://www.bradmcgehee.com/videos/

This video on technet:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ee861095

This site also has more general SQL Server video tutorials (and a few profiler ones)
http://www.sqlshare.com/channel.aspx?cat=96b0a352-6498-dd11-bebd-001143eb4af9

Answer (score 2):

You will find some great "real world" tips to improve SQL Server performance here: http://sqlfeed.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding here a great series from SQL Server Central, [Stairway to Server side tracing](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72363/), which is treating not only Profiler, but also server side tracing. I'm sure you'll love it's detail. It's treating most cases you'd need regarding the action of profiling a server.